# problemas con los CORS en .net core 7 y angular 15

Tags: angular, .net-core, module, cors

Quisiera su apoyo para lograr superar la siguiente situacion, tengo una api en .net core 7 y el front en angular 15, aparentemente ya configurado el tema del CORS pero solo funciona para uno de mis servicios de angular que es el de login. He intentado y revisado ya bastantes documentaciones pero no logro solucionar.

A continuación la configuración en .net

`builder.Services.AddCors(options =>`
`{`
`options.AddPolicy(name: "Global_Policy", policy =>` {
`policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();`
`});`
`});`

`app.UseCors("Global_Policy");`

Nota: La app en Angular está dividida en módulos no se si eso influya en el problema